# Haar detection - save Mat of image in order to get and show previous frame

Tags: c++, opencv

I am using Haar detection in my hobby project, the detection is done on a video stream. Once Haar detects something I imshow it, this is how it looks like: `Mat faceROI = frame_gray(faces[i]); 
imshow( "Detection", faceROI);`

While the video is running I am getting detections and the `Mat` is getting updated/overwritten with a new image of the object. What I want to do now is to save `Mat` so when a new detections occure I get both the **previous** and current frame. I'll guess I have to save the Mat in some way and then update it so *current -> previous* and so on.

```
imshow( "Previous detection", previousROI);` <- want to be able to do this
```

In case you want to see the whole code, I am doing this: http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/objdetect/cascade_classifier/cascade_classifier.html

Help is much appreciated!

Comment: So, `faceROI` is the ROI of one of the faces inside that frame, and the reason it's redeclaring each for loop iteration is because it's now looking at a different face in that same frame. 

Are you trying to get an image with all of ROIs of faces in that frame? Or are you trying to compare all the faceROIs in one frame to all the faceROIs in the next frame? 

If you're trying to compare all the faceROIs in one frame to the faceROIs in the second frame, setting up a global `Mat previousROI` and `clone`-ing it from `faceROI` after the imshows should work (eyes will still be there, though)

Comment: @RachelL  1. "Are you trying to get an image with all of ROIs of faces in that frame?" No, I just care about getting one at a time. 2. "are you trying to compare all the faceROIs in one frame to all the faceROIs in the next frame?" Not doing that either, but I will do it later, therefore I want to save the previous frame. 3. "If you're trying to compare all the faceROIs in one frame to the faceROIs in the second frame, setting up a global Mat previousROI and clone-ing it from faceROI" I will try to compare them later on, but first I need to save **one** previous frame. 4. eyes = I don't use it

Comment: @RachelL Therefore I don't think cloning and showing is a good solution as it doesn't solve my problem. The previous image/frame must be saved somehow.

Comment: @c-j-blue Would storing each faceROI in a vector of Mats be more like what you're looking for? You could `push_back` each faceROI into it, and then iterate through the vector later to grab the ones you want. (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/)

Answer (score 1):

You might have and easier time if you don't split the detect/display into a separate function. I've modified the OpenCV documentation code below. Keep in mind I haven't compiled or run this so there may be some errors, but it should give you an idea of a different way to address the issue.

```
/** @function main */
int main( int argc, const char** argv )
{
    CvCapture* capture;
    Mat frame;

    //-- 1. Load the cascades
    if( !face_cascade.load( face_cascade_name ) ){ printf("--(!)Error loading\n"); return -1; };
    if( !eyes_cascade.load( eyes_cascade_name ) ){ printf("--(!)Error loading\n"); return -1; };

    //-- 2. Read the video stream
    capture = cvCaptureFromCAM( -1 );
    if( capture )
    {
        //store faces here
        std::vector<Mat> prev_faces;
        std::vector<Mat> current_faces;

        while( true )
        {
            frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );

            //-- 3. Apply the classifier to the frame
            if( !frame.empty() )
            {
                std::vector<Rect> faces;
                Mat frame_gray;

                cvtColor( frame, frame_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY );
                equalizeHist( frame_gray, frame_gray );

                //-- Detect faces
                face_cascade.detectMultiScale( frame_gray, faces, 1.1, 2, 0|CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(30, 30) );

                for( size_t i = 0; i < faces.size(); i++ )
                {
                    Mat faceROI = frame_gray( faces[i] );
                    current_faces.push_back(faceROI); //adds all of the current detections to a vector
                }

                if (prev_faces.size() > 0 && current_faces.size() > 0)
                {
                    //  do stuff with prev_faces and current_faces
                    //  for(int i = 0; i < prev_faces.size(); i++){
                    //      imshow("previous", prev_faces[i])
                    //  }
                    //  for(int i = 0; i < prev_faces.size(); i++){
                    //      imshow("current",  current_faces[i])
                    //  }
                    //  imshow("stuff", other_cool_Mats_I_made_by_analysing_and_comparing_prev_and_current)
                }
                prev_faces = current_faces;
                current_faces.erase(current_faces.begin(), current_faces.end());

            else
            { printf(" --(!) No captured frame -- Break!"); break; }

            int c = waitKey(10);
            if( (char)c == 'c' ) { break; }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Tried it out, it works but not really as I want, it only gives the previous frame every 5 detection or so.

Comment: Not knowing your full intent, I've added arbitrary conditions of `*_faces.size() > 0`. Perhaps that (or any other condition you may have included) is affecting how / when your code executes. That is a best guess, it is difficult to debug your code without seeing it.